# ISNUMBER (MATCH) keeps showing a false statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the duplicate numbers from two worksheets.  sheet 1 is where I am trying to show a true or false using MATCH.[1](https://ibb.co/dm0SRhK).  sheet 2 is where I am a map with the locations of items.  [2](https://ibb.co/VpbSjVr).  I am using the formula =ISNUMBER(MATCH(E4,sheet2!$A$3:$Y$113,0)) but everything is coming up with a false even though some numbers should be true.

Link to excel spreadsheet is below.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvzXyiSyMirHljk5TqoDCSOlkjNq

I am using this as work so I cade use any macros or VBA. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why put isnumber() around the match() , why not use isnumber() just to test cell E4 ?

Comment: Match() looks up in a column only! It should be 
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(E4,sheet2!$A$3:$A$113,0))

Comment: @Faseeh match will work with an array either horizontal or vertical...

Comment: @Solar Mike, yes correct I meant to say that it will not work with multiple rows or multiple column, a single row or single column will work fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## MATCH Trouble: COUNTIF Comes to Rescue

The reason always `FALSE` is returned is because `MATCH` only works with a one-row range or a one-column range e.g. `$A$3:$Y$3` or `$A$3:$A$113`.

So you should use `COUNTIF`. Copy the following formula to cell `K4` of `Sheet1` of the uploaded workbook:

> ```
> =IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$3:$Y$113,E3),TRUE,FALSE)
> ```

which is actually 'short' for:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$3:$Y$113,E3)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but still didn't work.  I have included the excel spreadsheet in a link for better reference.

Comment: @nobb666: I didn't even look at the range i.e. that it wasn't a one-column range, so my answer was wrong. I've updated it now with a working solution. Sorry. BTW the link to the workbook was a great idea. It opened my eyes.